# Audio MD5 Checksum with ffmpeg

Tags: windows, command-line, audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm getting these results under Windows (`ffmpeg version N-78636-g45d3af9`)

```
ffmpeg.exe -i TEST.mp3 -c:a copy -f md5 -
MD5=cb017003b355c2b39d71e8020bd76f5b

ffmpeg.exe -i TEST.mp3 -f md5 -
MD5=7bbe06733ddc930c8a120bced0f3fad9
```

Why is it different? And what is the proper way to calculate MD5 checksum for audio data only? How do I make ffmpeg return the string (`MD5=xxxxx.xxxxx`) only?

Comment: Next time asking about ffmpeg, please include the full, uncut command line output.

Comment: just thought it's easy to understand when I cut it! but nex time I will for sure ... Thanks

Comment: Sure thanks. Sometimes it's not necessary, but it helps us catch minor errors or give explanations better suited to the question.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63608717/111036) which shows how to use `-map` to select which stream to checksum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#md5-1) for the MD5 muxer, it says:

> By default audio frames are converted to signed 16-bit raw audio and video frames to raw video before computing the hash.

So, in your second command (without specifying any codec option), this'd be the equivalent of `-c:a pcm_s16le`, while in your first example, you keep the MP3 audio bitstream. That's why they have different checksums.

The proper way would probably be to disable video streams (if the MP3 file contains artwork, for example) using `-vn`:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i TEST.mp3 -vn -f md5 -
```

You can disable the other output by redirecting stderr:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i TEST.mp3 -vn -f md5 - 2>NUL
```

On Linux, use `/dev/null` instead of `NUL`.

Comment: now I get this MD5=6e08f3bb7e5e8cc27e2f77a7817abbba a bit more confused ... but I will change the file tags and see how it will be :)

Comment: If the MP3 contains artwork, it'll be rendered as a video stream and used in the MD5 calculation unless you disable it with `-vn`. If you show the complete ffmpeg output in your question, we can have a better look at it.

Comment: after deleting all tags from file:

ffmpeg.exe -i TEST.mp3 -vn -f md5 - 2>NUL
MD5=6e08f3bb7e5e8cc27e2f77a7817abbba

ffmpeg.exe -i TEST.mp3 -f md5 - 2>NUL
MD5=6e08f3bb7e5e8cc27e2f77a7817abbba

ffmpeg.exe -i TEST.mp3 -c:a copy -f md5 - 2>
MD5=886d08f4e9c5450ee12796b006307a33

Comment: That makes sense now. (I was asking about the *full* output, without the redirection, to see what kind of tags there were, but you seem to have resolved the problem.)